# Parsing XML Feed with PHP: Group Output by Category

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse data from a job board XML feed. The basic feed syntax looks like this:

```
<jobs>
<job>
    <title>
    <![CDATA[ Senior Data Analyst ]]>
    </title>
    <category>
    <![CDATA[ Analytics ]]>
    </category>
    <url>
    <![CDATA[
    http://www.mysite.com/careers/Senior-Data-Analyst.html
    ]]>
    </url>
</job>
<job>
    <title>
    <![CDATA[ Infrastructure Administrator ]]>
    </title>
    <category>
    <![CDATA[ Information Technology ]]>
    </category>
    <url>
    <![CDATA[
    http://www.mysite.com/careers/Infrastructure-Administrator.html
    ]]>
    </url>
</job>
</jobs>
```

I already know how to parse the basic info using a foreach loop:

```
<?php
    $jobs = simplexml_load_file('jobfeed.xml');

    foreach ($jobs as $jobDetails):
        $category = $jobDetails->category;
        $title = $jobDetails->title;
        $url = $jobDetails->url;

        echo '<li>Category: ',$category,'<br>Title: ',$title,'<br>URL: ',$url,'</li>';
    endforeach;
?>
```

But I want to group each job by category, so it looks like this:

- Analytics

  - Senior Data Analyst
  - Some Other Kind of Analyst
- Information Technology

  - Infrastructure Administrator

But I don't know how to loop through the category data and group the output. Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: First step would be to sort $jobs by its category field, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but you could easily group the output like so:

```
function output_list($jobs = array())
{
    $data = array();

    foreach($jobs as $job_details)
    {
        $category = $job_details->category;
        $title    = $job_details->title;
        $url      = $job_details->url;

        if(!isset($data[$category]))
        {
            $data[$category] = array();
        }

        $data[$category][] = '<li>Category: '.$category.'<br>Title: '.$title.'<br>URL: '.$url.'</li>';
    }

    foreach($data as $category => $items)
    {
        $data[$category] = '<li><ul>'.implode('', $items).'</ul></li>';
    }

    return '<ul>'.implode('', $data).'</ul>'; 
}

echo output_list($jobs);
```

Comment: Hi Justin, I'm getting a PHP error from the ExpressionEngine template parser: "Illegal offset type in isset or empty". Looks to be similar to the error in @Greg's code.

Comment: What line number is the error on? I assume it has something to do with $data array not being set properly. I tested it on my send, and not getting any errors. I will try to test it again to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $jobs = simplexml_load_file('jobfeed.xml');

    // We will store each category in an array. Each job in each category will be
    // an array storing the Title and URL.
    $categoryArray = array();

    // Loop over XML structure as before.
    foreach ($jobs as $jobDetails):
        $category = $jobDetails->category;
        $title = $jobDetails->title;
        $url = $jobDetails->url;

        // If the current category is not in the array yet, add it.
        if(empty($categoryArray[$category])) {
            $categoryArray[$category] = array();
        }
        // If the current category exists, add the job details to it.
        $categoryArray[$category][] = array(
            "Title" => $title, 
            "Url" => $url
        );
    endforeach;

    // Now we can loop over the sorted array, and output the data as required.
    foreach($categoryArray as $categoryName => $jobArray):
        echo '<li>Category: ' . $category;

        // Within each category, output an inner list for each job.
        echo '<ul>';    
        foreach($jobArray as $job) {
            echo '<li>Title: ' . $job["Title"] . '<br>URL: ' . $job["Url"] . '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Greg,

There's a semicolon missing after the `echo '</ul>'` at the end which was causing an error.

The PHP code is being run through the ExpressionEngine template parser, and I get this error (after fixing the semicolon thing):

"Illegal offset type in isset or empty"

Which seems to revolve around the "if the current category is not in the array yet" part.

Comment: @kgrote sorry, I had another typo in the code! Should work now.